# mysql_query to only show posts by the user

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I'm creating a twitter-like stream of posts using PHP. If the user only wants to see posts that he created, how should I write the mysql query?

Here's what I have now: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timeline ORDER BY dt DESC");`

I assume that I need to add a `WHERE` after timeline to indicate the user, but not sure what the proper code is.  Would it be `WHERE $_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: Could you please add `timeline` table structure to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right lines.

Watch the contents of $_SESSION['username']. You should really escape it first:

```
$usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
```

then

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timeline WHERE username = '$usr' ORDER BY dt DESC ");
```

I don't know what your user name field is called, so substitute.

Note: `mysql` is deprecated - use mysqli or PDO

Comment: excellent, thanks!  I actually just called that field username.:)  It's not giving me errors, but it's also not pulling any of the user's posts.  Guessing it's not recognizing the session's username and that I did something wrong not to set the session properly to pass in the current username.  Any advice for me to check the session setting?

Comment: Use `if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) {echo 'No username in session';}` to check the user name, or `var_dump($_SESSION)` to look at it all.  Assemble the query in a variable before you submit it ( `$query = "SELECT..."`, then add `echo $query;` right before you `mysql_query($query);`. That'll tell you exactly what your query is.

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't recommend this, it should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM timeline 
WHERE user = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

I would suggest using paramaterized queries and using pdo instead!

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to teach myself php so thanks for the warning.  No fear though, just experimenting really.  Nothing going live yet. :)

Comment: It's not giving me any errors, but it's also not pulling any of the user's posts.  Guessing it's not recognizing the session's username.  Any idea how I would set the session user to pull in his posts?

Comment: @JeffCloud -- what value does `SESSION['username']` equal?  Does that value exist in your timeline table?

Comment: It equals the username the user created as their profile name. Exactly like a twitter handle.  I have username in the timeline table. I also have user_id in the timeline table and maybe that's better to use.